# Expose dummy URL for junit

Tags: java, junit, httpurlconnection

I am writing JUnit for a class that opens a HttpURLConnection for a hard-coded URL. How can I expose any dummy URL that will return 200 response. Like can I create any dummy server?

Comment: Sure, one **can** create a dummy server. But what exactly is the question? You see - if you want a "dummy" URL, but a real connection to that URL; then the URL can't be "dummy" in the first place. You need a component sitting on the over end, ready to pick up the phone and answer incoming calls. So the easiest answer would be a very stupid dummy that just does that.

Comment: I just need a solution for this problem. Whether it can be achieved through dummy Server or something else. So far I think that Jetty can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` can do so.
A [HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) is bound to an IP address and port number and listens for incoming TCP connections from clients on this address.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a unit test (not a system/integration test) then you should use a [mocking framework](http://mockito.org/) to create a mock `HttpURLConnection` and configure the mock to return the response that you need.

Comment: I cannot mock 'HttpURLConnection' as this code is written in original method for which I am writing test case. I can only pass domainName and port as a parameter to this method.

Comment: Ok, then I would say that unless you can refactor the code it won't be possible to write a true unit test for that code - the outcome of the test will always depend on whatever server you use doing the right thing, rather than just on your code being correct.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am thinking of some in-memory server, because that server should be available during automated testing in Jenkins.

Comment: There are some possibilities here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966946/fake-http-server-for-testing-purpose